# Android errors/crashing on click

Tags: java, android, json

I'm trying to do some simple JSON parsing to get data from a URL, and change some values on the screen.  Currently, however, the application locks up when the button is clicked and eventually crashes.    I am pulling data from

http://dev4.vcsonline.com/deding/vpmi_mobile/WebAPI/WebAPI/api/address

onclick listener and async task:

```
    Pull_Data = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Pull_Data);
    Pull_Data.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new MyAsyncTask().execute(URL);

        }


    });


private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        SetValues(args[0]);
        return null;
    }
```

JSON pull/manipulation code:

```
 public static JSONObject getJSONfromURL(String url){

    //initialize
    InputStream is = null;
    String result = "";
    JSONObject JArray = null;

    //http post
    try{
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
    }

    // convert response to string
    try{
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"),8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        result = sb.toString();
        //client_Address1.setText(result);
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }


    // try parse the string to a JSON object

    try{
            JArray = new JSONObject(result);
    }catch(JSONException e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }
    return JArray;
}

public void SetValues(String url){
    JSONObject json = getJSONfromURL(url);

    // get the element that holds the addresses
    try{
        JSONArray addresses = json.getJSONArray("Address");

        // get the proper items
        JSONObject e = addresses.getJSONObject(0);
        client_Address1.setText(e.getString("addressLineOne"));
        client_Address2.setText(e.getString("addressLineTwo"));
        client_Address3.setText(e.getString("addressCity") + ", " + e.getString("addressState") + " " + e.getString("addressZip"));
        client_Id.setText(e.getString("clientID"));
    }catch(JSONException e){
    Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }
}
```

Finally, logcat entries:

```
 08-21 11:49:42.860: E/log_tag(30551): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException
 08-21 11:49:42.860: E/log_tag(30551): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
 08-21 11:49:42.865: W/dalvikvm(30551): threadid=12: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c101f8) 
 08-21 11:49:42.870: E/AndroidRuntime(30551): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
 08-21 11:49:42.870: E/AndroidRuntime(30551): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
 08-21 11:49:42.870: E/AndroidRuntime(30551):   at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
 08-21 11:49:42.870: E/AndroidRuntime(30551):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
 08-21 11:49:42.870: E/AndroidRuntime(30551):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
 08-21 11:49:42.870: E/AndroidRuntime(30551):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
 08-21 11:49:42.870: E/AndroidRuntime(30551):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
 08-21 11:49:42.870: E/AndroidRuntime(30551):   at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
 08-21 11:49:42.870: E/AndroidRuntime(30551):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
 08-21 11:49:42.870: E/AndroidRuntime(30551):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
 08-21 11:49:42.870: E/AndroidRuntime(30551):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
 08-21 11:49:42.870: E/AndroidRuntime(30551): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 08-21 11:49:42.870: E/AndroidRuntime(30551):   at com.example.networking.MainActivity.SetValues(MainActivity.java:353)
 08-21 11:49:42.870: E/AndroidRuntime(30551):   at com.example.networking.MainActivity$MyAsyncTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:222)
 08-21 11:49:42.870: E/AndroidRuntime(30551):   at com.example.networking.MainActivity$MyAsyncTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
 08-21 11:49:42.870: E/AndroidRuntime(30551):   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
 08-21 11:49:42.870: E/AndroidRuntime(30551):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
 08-21 11:49:42.870: E/AndroidRuntime(30551):   ... 5 more
```

Comment: the link has xml data.

Comment: it has both, android is pulling it back as json, just like internet explorer and firefox do.  Chrome pulls back xml

Comment: yes it's a xml data not a json format

Comment: the same application has an xml parser that was returning no information on the same url, and the one time I got it to print to a string it returned what looked like json formatting.

Comment: make sure an print out result in your methode getJSONfromURL , becouse I think you are getting xml

Comment: what is line 353 `MainActivity.java`

Comment: line 353: JSONArray addresses = json.getJSONArray("Address");  tried a couple things there, blank string, ArrayOfAddress and Address

Comment: Try setting a breakpoint in `getJSONArray`, on the line `result = sb.toString();` and see what's actually in `result`

Comment: @MarshallTigerus are you sure what you are getting is a json . does not look so from http://dev4.vcsonline.com/deding/vpmi_mobile/WebAPI/WebAPI/api/address

Comment: you are getting `NullPointerException` because current api accept only HttpPost request instead of HttpPost, second point is current JsonOject and JsonArray string not content any Address key

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK also the the link looks like xml not json

Comment: the result string is null then <error(s)_during_the_evaluation> after it is set by sb-toString();

Comment: @Raghunandan : i tried api link with chrome Http poster returning valid json object when im making get request

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK yes. its a post request. you are right

Comment: changed it to a get request and still crashes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the Opera Dragonfly tool to make an Http POST request to the Url you provided (with no posted data):

Request:

```
POST /deding/vpmi_mobile/WebAPI/WebAPI/api/address HTTP/1.1
Host: dev4.vcsonline.com
Content-Length: 0
```

This is the response I get back:

```
HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Sun, 25 Aug 2013 17:18:51 GMT
```

Note the `No Content`. It looks like your web service does not accept POST requests?

Comment: I didn't code the site, so I'm not sure.  Is there any way to recode the above to force it to GET isntead of POST

Comment: Well, in your code I see this line: `HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);`.  Not familiar with the API off the top of my head, but I'd check that out to see if there was a "Get" version.

Comment: It seems with `GET` and no other headers it returns JSON.  You can control the returned data-type it seems with these headers: `Accept: application/json` or `Accept: text/xml`

Comment: using get still crashes it.  I am going to try to use the headers to force xml, and use the other code I have that I know actually works (but was receiving no data because of the format) and see if it works.

Comment: At any rate you should probably just set a breakpoint in the method that generates the error, and startup the app in debug mode, so you can step through the code and inspect the intermediate values of the variables to see why/where it's failing.  Might save a lot of time!

Comment: eclipse's debugger and I don't get along very well, bu I will try to use it to wort it out.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
        new MyAsyncTask().execute(URL);
```

seems risky to me. Since you're not creating any reference to the new MyAsyncTask instance, it's possible that it's getting garbage-collected. Try assigning it to a member variable:

```
        mAsyncTask = new MyAsyncTask();
        mAsyncTask.execute(URL);
```

where mAsyncTask is a member of your Activity.

This change may or may not fix this problem, but it could prevent others.

Comment: Uh, I have used `AsyncTask` without keeping a reference to it and it worked fine. :)

Comment: GC is capricious. Unless you can find something that guarantees that the AsyncTask object won't be GC'd while it's running -- even if the app doesn't maintain a reference to it -- I'd consider this a possible failure mode. Not guaranteed by any means, but possible.

Comment: @DanBreslau i don't think that's a issue here

Comment: That is not risky at all and is a typical usage. AsyncTask is a singleton with a static task runner that maintains a queue of pending/active tasks. There is 0 chance that it will be garbage collected while running because there is an internal reference to the task whether you save a reference it or not.

Comment: I seem to be outvoted here, so I won't continue the argument beyond this. However: 1) I don't see anything in the docs for AsyncTask that suggests that it's not subject to GC before it stops running; and 2) a very quick look at the AsyncTask code doesn't show me where there's a reference from the Thread to the AsyncTask. So I'm not sure where this claimed guarantee comes from. (It's possible that we're all correct, if the AsyncTask is a wrapper that can be GC'd without damaging the operation of the underlying Thread.) But, again, I won't press the issue any further.

Comment: I changed it just to see, and it had no effect on removing errors or making it work.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `setValues()` which updates the UI controls in the `doInBackground` method which does not run on the UI thread.

Instead, shift it to `onPostExecute()` which runs on the UI thread. By that I mean updating the UI controls. You must do all the network, and any time-taking processing, in `doInBackground`

Do let me know if this worked.

Comment: in that case you should get a exception called from wrong thread. yes you are right op is setting text view in doInbackground. that's one mistake

Comment: Multiple issues here: As `Jrop` showed, no data. Then the issue I pointed out. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and after the i figured it out that the problem was in HttpPost reference.So, I changed it in HttpGet and my problem solved.

try this code:

```
public static JSONObject getJSONfromURL(String url){
//initialize
InputStream is = null;
String result = "";
JSONObject JArray = null;

//http post
try{
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    is = entity.getContent();
}catch(Exception e){
    Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
}

// convert response to string
try{
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"),8);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
        sb.append(line + "\n");
    }
    is.close();
    result = sb.toString();
    //client_Address1.setText(result);
}catch(Exception e){
    Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
}


// try parse the string to a JSON object

try{
        JArray = new JSONObject(result);
}catch(JSONException e){
    Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
}
return JArray;
 }


 public void SetValues(String url){
JSONObject json = getJSONfromURL(url);

// get the element that holds the addresses
try{
    JSONArray addresses = json.getJSONArray("Address");

    // get the proper items
    JSONObject e = addresses.getJSONObject(0);
    client_Address1.setText(e.getString("addressLineOne"));
    client_Address2.setText(e.getString("addressLineTwo"));
    client_Address3.setText(e.getString("addressCity") + ", " + e.getString("addressState") + " " + e.getString("addressZip"));
    client_Id.setText(e.getString("clientID"));
}catch(JSONException e){
Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
}
}
```

Comment: tried this, still get a crash.  I've also been trying to go line by line in the debugger and not getting any useful information or errors.  Quite frustrating.